# MySQL: How to construct a given query

Tags: mysql

I am not a MySQL guru at all, and I would really appreciate if someone takes some time to help me. I have three tables as shown below:

```
TEAM(teamID, teamName, userID)
YOUTH_TEAM(youthTeamID, youthTeamName, teamID)
YOUTH_PLAYER(youthPlayerID, youthPlayerFirstName, youthPlayerLastName, youthPlayerAge, youthPlayerDays, youthPlayerRating, youthPlayerPosition, youthTeamID)
```

And this is the query that I have now:

```
SELECT team.teamName, youth_team.youthTeamName, youth_player.*
FROM youth_player
    INNER JOIN youth_team ON youth_player.youthTeamID = youth_team.youthTeamID
    INNER JOIN team ON youth_team.teamID = team.teamID
WHERE youth_player.youthPlayerAge < 18
AND youth_player.youthPlayerDays < 21
AND youth_player.youthPlayerRating >= 5.5
```

What I would like to add to this query is a more thorough checks like the following:

- if player has 16 years, and his position is scorer, then the player should have at least 7 rating in order to be returned
- if player has 15 years, and his position is playmaker, then the player should have at least 5.5 rating in order to be returned
- etc., etc.

How can I implement these requirements in my query (if possible), and is that query going to be a bad-way solution? Is it maybe going to be better if I do the selection with PHP code (if we suppose I use PHP) instead of doing it in the query?

Comment: if the criterias are static and don't change, you could create another table with the fields "age, position, minimum_rating" and join it against the other tables.

Comment: First let's talk about schema.  What is the relation between team and youth_team?  Also, is there a player table which is similar to youth_player?  What I am trying to get to is whether you actually have more tables than you actually need and are, in-essence adding new tables where you could represent differences between team/youth team as a column or columns on team table.

Comment: @sled Criterias will be static, I didn't think of the idea of another table, but I think it's going to be a good way to solve this, because that way I can also make changes to the requirements through a user interface, instead of hard coding them. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @MikeBrant team is the senior team, I probably should have named it better. So the youth team belongs to that given senior team. There is no player table (at this moment), it's only the one for youth players. I don't quite understand you about the last part, but maybe you can share some other view on how you would represent the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution with an additional "criteria/filter" table:

```
-- SAMPLE TEAMS: Yankees, Knicks:
INSERT INTO `team` VALUES (1,'Yankees',2),(2,'Knicks',1);

-- SAMPLE YOUTH TEAMS: Yankees Juniors, Knicks Juniors
INSERT INTO `youth_team` VALUES (1,'Knicks Juniors',1),(2,'Yankees Juniors',2);

-- SAMPLE PLAYERS
INSERT INTO `youth_player` VALUES       
  (1,'Carmelo','Anthony',16,20,7.5,'scorer',1),
  (2,'Amar\'e','Stoudemire',17,45,5.5,'playmaker',1),
  (3,'Iman','Shumpert',15,15,6.1,'playmaker',1),
  (4,'Alex','Rodriguez',18,60,3.5,'playmaker',2),
  (5,'Hiroki','Kuroda',16,17,8.7,'scorer',2),
  (6,'Ichiro','Suzuki',19,73,8.3,'playmaker',2);

-- CRITERIA TABLE
CREATE TABLE `criterias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_rating` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- SAMPLE CRITERIAS
-- AGE=16, POSITION=SCORER, MIN_RATING=7
-- AGE=15, POSITION=PLAYMAKER, MIN_RATING=5.5
INSERT INTO `criterias` VALUES (1,16,'scorer',7), (2,15,'playmaker',5.5);
```

Now your query could look like:

```
SELECT team.teamName, youth_team.youthTeamName, youth_player.*
FROM youth_player
    CROSS JOIN criterias
    INNER JOIN youth_team ON youth_player.youthTeamID = youth_team.youthTeamID
    INNER JOIN team ON youth_team.teamID = team.teamID
WHERE 
(
    youth_player.youthPlayerAge < 18
    AND youth_player.youthPlayerDays < 21
    AND youth_player.youthPlayerRating >= 5.5
) 
AND
(
    youth_player.youthPlayerAge = criterias.age
    AND youth_player.youthPlayerPosition = criterias.position
    AND youth_player.youthPlayerRating >= criterias.min_rating
)
```

This yields (shortened results):

```
teamName  youthTeamName     youthPlayerName   Age   Days  Rating  Position   
=============================================================================
Yankees   "Knicks Juniors"  Carmelo Anthony   16    20    7.5     scorer        
Yankees   "Knicks Juniors"  Iman Shumpert     15    15    6.1     playmaker   
Knicks    "Yankees Juniors" Hiroki Kuroda     16    17    8.7     scorer
```

Comment: I have solved the issue this way when your first proposed it in the comment, so I am going to select your answer as accepted, although I must say that the query is not so fast as I wanted to be. Anyways, until I come up with some other solution this will be my implementation, so thanks for your help and answer.

Comment: hi, did you index your table properly?

Comment: It seems I didn't... I am going to work on that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in the query is quite fine...... as long as it doesn't get too messed up. You can perform a lot of stuff in your query, but it may get hard to maintain. So if it gets too long and you want somebody else to take a look at it, you should split it up or find a solution in your php-script.

As for your requirements add this too your WHERE-part:

```
AND 
(
    (YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerAge >= 16 AND YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerPosition = 'scorer' AND YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerRating >= 7)
    OR (YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerAge >= 15 AND YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerPosition = 'playmaker' AND YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerRating >= 5.5)
)
```

Comment: I thought of doing something like this (although not knowing if it's going to be valid), but thinking of it now it's going to get really messy when you take into account that there are around 10 positions for the players... the query will take 30 lines. Anyways, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome :-) There are always frameworks which help you building queries ;-) Or you just use function like $sql .= "OR ". playercriteria(15,'keeper',4) with function playercriteria($age,$position,$rating){return " (YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerAge >= $age AND YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerPosition = '$position' AND YOUTH_PLAYER.youthPlayerRating >= $rating)";}